# How does Stack decide on dependencies?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I just made [a fork](https://github.com/emhoracek/xml/commit/3e1bd12882d7c452d76e39e1db1b95577f38d4d7) to fix a bug in html-conduit, which my templating library depended on. I maintain an app that depends on that templating library.

So, I [updated my library's `stack.yaml`](https://github.com/positiondev/larceny/pull/64) to point to the fork:

```
extra-deps:
  [...]
  - git: https://github.com/emhoracek/xml.git
    commit: 3e1bd12882d7c452d76e39e1db1b95577f38d4d7
    subdirs:
       - xml-conduit
       - html-conduit
```

And wrote a test to make sure that updating that dependency fixed the bug. It did! Yay.

Then I updated my app to point to the updated templating library:

```
packages:
  [...]
  - location:
      git: https://github.com/positiondev/larceny
      commit: ba743c58ff4ac2606f67336e5e557deacb416ed8
    extra-dep: true
```

I checked to make sure that this fixed the bug in my app, but it *didn't*. Until I added my fork of `html-conduit` to my app's extra-deps, it still had the bug.

What's going on? Why doesn't Stack use the version of `html-conduit` I specified in my library's `stack.yaml` when it's deciding what version my app should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `stack` command only references a single `stack.yaml` file - the one that's in the current directory, or maybe some parent directory.  Libraries you depend on don't need to have a `stack.yaml` file, and it's ignored if it exists.

This keeps the version specification simple.  There are no rules for handling the case where two `stack.yaml` files ask for different versions of the same library, because no build ever consults two `stack.yaml` files.

On the other hand, the `.cabal` file for each library is consulted, so you will get an error early in the build if some `.cabal` file requires a library for which the `stack.yaml` doesn't specify a version, or if the version bounds in a `.cabal` don't match the specific version in `stack.yaml`.

Comment: Ohhhhh. So if I had bumped the version of html-conduit in my fork, and had referenced the new version in my library's cabal file and in my app, Stack could have figured it out?

Comment: If I understand the scenario, you would have gotten an error in that case.  The version of `http-conduit` specified by your app`s `stack.yaml` (by way of the Stackage snapshot) wouldn't match the lower bound in your library's `.cabal`.  You'd still need to add the `extra-dep` to your app's `stack.yaml.` . My last paragraph was just to contrast the way `stack` treats the two files, because I think the difference confuses people.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for the great answer!